# compilation error during gatling load test

Tags: scala, mqtt, load-testing, gatling, gatling-plugin

I'm trying to write a simulation and i want to be able to run the simulation.
I get an error while trying to $mvn gatling:execute.

My pom has the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-charts</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and the following plugins:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <scalaVersion>2.12.3</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>performanceTests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <simulationClass>simulations.SimulationClass</simulationClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the error that i came across:

```
12:50:36.313 [main][WARN ][ZincCompiler.scala:141] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - 
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.gatling.app.Gatling
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:42)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
```

Included dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

But now i get a new error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
at com.github.mnogu.gatling.mqtt.protocol.MqttProtocolOptionPart.<init>(MqttProtocol.scala:124)
at com.github.mnogu.gatling.mqtt.protocol.MqttProtocol$.apply(MqttProtocol.scala:24)
at com.github.mnogu.gatling.mqtt.protocol.MqttProtocolBuilder$.apply(MqttProtocolBuilder.scala:13)
at com.github.mnogu.gatling.mqtt.Predef$.mqtt(Predef.scala:9)
at simulations.SimulationClass.<init>(SimulationClass.scala:10)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:79)
at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:64)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:59)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:43)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:35)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
```

...

Any leads regarding this problem would be of great help.

Thank you

Comment: I Was getting the similar kind of error. Earlier I was using gatling-core "3.0.2" and scala "2.11.8". I just downgraded the gatling-core version to "2.3.1" and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error says that you are missing following dependency,

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.gatling/gatling-app -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**Updated**

Your second error is mainly because the jar file that your code refers at runtime is not the same jar file that is used at compile time. So make sure that you are using the same jar while compiling and while running.

For that, you can delete the dependent jar files, maven clean your project and recompile and run the program.

Comment: included the dependency and now i see another error.

Comment: Followed what you have mentioned. I still get the same error.

Comment: how are you running the job ? in local mode or in distributed mode? which line are you getting the error? can you share your codes?

Comment: I was running it locally. Looks like the external jar only supported gatling core version 2.2.3. Which might have caused the error. I have included an answer explaining the details.

Comment: great to hear that. I knew that its a jar issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the external jar i was using was compliant only with gatling core 2.2.3. Reverting the gatling core version to 2.2.3 and scala version to 2.11.8 solved the problem.

Here is how my pom now looks:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <scalaVersion>2.11.8</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>performanceTests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <simulationClass>simulations.SimulationClass</simulationClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```