# Error during gatling load test - ClassNotFoundException: io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler

Tags: java, maven, gatling

I am trying to run gatling load tests and got an error message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.gatling.compiler.ZincCompiler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:43)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:34)
```

My dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and plugins:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <resourcesFolder>src/test/resources/perf-test-cases</resourcesFolder>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and versions:

```
    <gatling.version>3.4.2</gatling.version>
    <gatling-plugin.version>3.1.1</gatling-plugin.version>
    <scala-maven-plugin.version>4.4.0</scala-maven-plugin.version>
```

I also have Scala plugin for IntelliJ 2020.3.12 installed.

I saw a thread [compilation error during gatling load test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766032/compilation-error-during-gatling-load-test)
and tried to add maven dependencies for gatling-core and gatling-app but it didn't help.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that maven broke your downloads and you have corrupted jars in your local maven cache. This kind of issue is completely silent, both when maven corrupts downloads and when the JVM fails to open the jars.

Try deleting everything in the `io.gatling` groupId in your local maven cache.